# Content showing with html tags inside un-ordered list (suspicious behavior)

Tags: jquery, post, html-lists

I have a LiveScript which is using `jQuery.post()` function to get data from server file category.php. The server file returns `<li><a href="#cellphones">cellphones</a></li><li><a href="#tablets">tablets</a></li><li><a href="#laptops">laptops</a></li>` but when I add it inside html unordered list using jQuery LiveScript. I am also getting the tags with content.

**script.js**

```
$.post("category.php", function(data) {
    $('#categories ul').text(data);
});
```

**index.php**

```
<div id="categories">
    <ul>

    </ul>
</div>
```

**CHROME showing..**

```
<li><a href="#cellphones">cellphones</a></li><li><a href="#tablets">tablets</a></li>   <li><a href="#laptops">laptops</a></li>
```

**Instead of**

cellphones

tablets

laptops

Comment: so.. ``text()`` is for text and ``html`` is for html. How simple was that. RESOLVED. By the way I'm new to jQuery

Comment: *I'm new* shouldn't be used as an excuse not to do research. http://api.jquery.com/text states: *"We need to be aware that this method escapes the string provided as necessary so that it will render correctly in HTML. To do so, it calls the DOM method .createTextNode(), which replaces special characters with their HTML entity equivalents (such as &lt; for <)."*

Comment: @ahren My apology. Next time I'll ask after research

Answer (score 1):

use

```
$.post("category.php", function(data) {
    $('#categories ul').html(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Use `.html()`

It is not weird. It is intended behaviour. For your case, use `.html()`:

```
$.post("category.php", function(data) {
    $('#categories ul').html(data);
});
```

#### Explanation from jQuery

**`.html()`**

> In an HTML document, `.html()` can be used to get the contents of any element. If the selector expression matches more than one element, only the first match will have its HTML content returned.

**`.text()`**

> Unlike the `.html()` method, `.text()` can be used in both XML and HTML documents. The result of the `.text()` method is a string containing the combined text of all matched elements. (Due to variations in the HTML parsers in different browsers, the text returned may vary in newlines and other white space.)

Answer (score 1):

```
$.post("category.php", function(data) {
$('#categories ul').text(data);
});
```

change text to html

```
$.post("category.php", function(data) {
  $('#categories ul').html(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$('#categories ul').html(data)` instead of `$('#categories ul').text(data)`